# A batch file that will delete the newest folder if there's more than 10

Tags: windows, batch-file, directory

I want to create a batch file (.bat) that can delete the *newest* folder in a folder of folders if there's more than 10 folders. If this is the directory tree:

```
\My Folders\
... \Old Videos\        (Created 2 Hours Ago)
... \Files\             (Created Last Month)
... \Pics\              (Created Last Week)
... \Powerpoints\       (Created Yesterday)
... \Videos\            (Created Several Days Ago)
... \Old Pics\          (Created Yesterday)
... \Movies\            (Created Yesterday)
... \Games\             (Created Yesterday)
... \Old Files\         (Created Last Month)
... \Downloads\         (Created Two Weeks Ago)
... \New Folder\        (Created Just Now)
```

So this batch file, when run, will delete New Folder (at the bottom) because there is more than 10 files in the folder (*excluding subfolders*), and it is the newest. If there was 12 folders in the directory tree (again, minus subfolders), the batch file would delete the 2 newest, and so on.

Is there a way to do this in Win10? I've messed around with it a bit, but haven't been able to do it.

Comment: Only count folders in My Folders\... or also the subfolders. I mean are the 11 folders you mentioned inside My Folders or also in subdirectories. Further just counting folders or also files?

Comment: @AndreKampling just the folders in My Folders\, not subfolders. Should have made that clearer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dir` has a lot of useful switches:
`/ad` to show folders only (no files)
`/od` to sort by date (oldest first)
`/tc` to take "created" date-time (default: "last-changed")
`/b` to show just the names.

Put a `for` loop around, skip the first 10 lines and you're done:

```cmd
@echo off
cd "My Folders"
for /f "skip=10 delims=" %%a in ('dir /ad /od /tc /b') do ECHO rd /s /q "%%a"
```

remove the `ECHO` if the output is what you want.

Comment: Oh, wait, problems ahoy. I've got this: `cd E:\main-folder\data\.minecraft\saves"
for /f "skip=10 delims=" %%a in ('dir /ad /o-d /tc /b') do ECHO rd /s /q "%%a"` and 11 folders in E:\main-folder\data\.minecraft\saves, but the newest one's not deleted.

Comment: You have to remove the `echo` in front of `rd` so that removing will take effect. Also this answer will sort "wrong", the oldest will be deleted, see my comment below my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The following batch script will do what you've asked for:

Usage: `batch.bat "path\folder with spaces" 11`

If it is okay with you, you can remove the `echo` in front of the `rd` command. You also could extend that to print the list first and then aks the user for confirmation to delete them.
This batch uses the `dir` command with the `/O:D` option to sort for dates (oldest first), `/A:D` option to show directories only, the /TC option to use the creation date and the `/B` to just get the names.

The `dir` command uses the last written time as default, if you want to change that use the /T switch (described here on [technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755121(v=ws.11).aspx)):

> `/t[[:]<TimeField>]`
>
> Specifies which time field to display or use for sorting. The following list describes each of the values you can use for TimeField:
>
> `c` Creation
>
> `a` Last access
>
> `w` Last written

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

rem Check if 2 arguments are passed
set INVARGS=0
if [%1] == [] set INVARGS=1
if [%2] == [] set INVARGS=1
if %INVARGS% == 1 (
   echo Usage: %0 ^<folder^> ^<count^>
   goto :EOF
)

set "folder=%~1"
set "count=%~2"

if not exist "%folder%" (
   echo The directory does not exists:
   echo    "%folder%"
   echo The program will exit.
   goto :EOF
)

pushd "%folder%"
set idx=1
rem dir command with date sort just directories
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /O:D /A:D /TC /B') do (
   if !idx! GEQ %count% (
      echo rd /s /q "%%F"
   )
   set /a idx=!idx!+1
)
popd
```

Comment: Works, but very large compared to the above answer.

Comment: Yes right. His answer would delete the oldest and not the newest. He uses `/O:-D` instead of `/O:D`.

Comment: Further his answer uses the creation date `/TC`.

Comment: @AndreKampling you are right with `/od`. But according to the question ("(Created 2 Hours Ago)`), the creation date `/tc` should be correct.

Comment: @Stephan: Yes sorry you're right the OP talks about creation date. Thank you!